# How to install gcc-4.4 on cygwin?

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I've installed [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe) environment on Windows.
There is gcc 4.3. How to install gcc 4.4 in this environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative is to build one yourself, but it will be extremely slow on cygwin. If you are a Linux user, you can build a *native* compiler (which runs in cmd.exe on windows, and produces native win32 binaries) on Linux. It is much faster (order of magnitude faster in my experience).

Otherwise, mingw is a good solution, although in my experience, the binary from [equation.com work better](ftp://ftp.equation.com/gcc/gcc-4.4.0-32.exe) for gcc 4.4 (there is no official gcc 4.4 from MinGW yet)

Comment: It takes a while but the compilation process is straight forward. Just a hint: You save quite a bit of time if you make sure you have all the required libraries installed (e.g. download the source, configure, build and install them). For GCC in C and C++ mode you need the following libs: GMP, MPFR and CLooG-PPL

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the cygwin environment for special reasons, I'd go for Mingw with the gcc 4.4. You can find builds on: http://www.tdragon.net/recentgcc/.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [MinGW FAQ](http://mingw.org/wiki/FAQ), reveals that its possible to pass requests to use the MinGW binaries instead of the ones shipped with Cygwin.

> For those who would like to use the Cygwin environment for development, yet generate non-Cygwin-dependant executables, a much easier option to "-mno-cygwin" does exist. Simply install Cygwin and the MinGW distribution in separate directories (i.e. "C:\CYGWIN" and "C:\MINGW"), and make sure that the "/bin" subdirectory beneath your MinGW installation comes before Cygwin's "/bin" subdirectory in your PATH environment variable (i.e. "PATH=%PATH%;C:\MINGW\BIN;C:\CYGWIN\BIN"). This will allow you access to all the UNIX tools you want, while ensuring that the instance of GCC used is the MinGW version. %%%
>
> Bear in mind that within the "/etc/profile" file, Cygwin by default places "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/bin", and "/bin" ahead of your system-level PATH. Therefore, it is not enough to have the MinGW's "/bin" ahead of Cygwin in your Windows path... it must also be set to come first within the Cygwin environment (either by modifying "/etc/profile" or setting it manually).