# How to downgrade the gcc compiler?

Tags: matlab, gcc, mex

I have to run a code. The code includes mex files. For building that code, it required gcc version of 4.4.
Following is the description of system

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2012
- Matlab 2017a

And gcc version of my system is:

`$gcc --version
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.4.0`

I do not know how to downgrade it. I have tried so many steps, but no use.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install it first - Please use a previous question on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011728/how-to-install-gcc-4-4-on-cygwin):

Next - choose to use it on Matlab via :

```
mex -setup
```

Comment: I have install it. And I have downloaded the setup from the link you had mentioned. But still I got the same version. Will you guide it more elaboratoley

Comment: Please attach the mex -setup output.

Answer (score 0):

@mano Here's my output of the mex -setup 
[image]